# What do these perl regular expression mean?

Tags: regex, perl

```
            chomp();         # Remove the newline. 
            $_ =~ s/\s*//;   # No extra spaces     
            $_ =~ s/\\//;    # Kill any line connector
```

I am not very familiar with Perl/regex. I am modifying an existing perl script with the above snippet. This chunk of code removes the newline character, spaces and line ending with '\' as connector.

My question is, in the following line, what do the two bold character mean? I understand that anything between '/  /' is regular expression. But,

1) What does the **s** preceding the '/   /' mean?

2) What does the second '/' at the end mean?

In $_ =~ **s**/\s* **/**/;

Comment: `s` is for replace found substring. `/` divides command sections. If it helps:  s/..what to look for../..with what to replace the found/

Comment: `$_ =~ s/\s*//;` means Substitute (`s/`) 0 or more spaces (`\s*`) with nothing (`//`), effectively deleting them

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html, [`s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2fPATTERN%2fREPLACEMENT%2fmsixpodualgcer)

Comment: `s/\\//` does not mean to remove line endings with backslash connector, it means remove **all** backslashes in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s` means "do replace".

```
$_ =~ s/SEARCH/REPLACE/;
```

So, `s/\s*//;` means find every white spaces and remove them (or replace them with empty string).

Comment: Thank you! That explains it!

Answer (score 2):

The "s" is the substitution function so it is saying "substitute"/"what matches here"/"with what's here"/

The "/" here is the opening and closing delimiter of the parameters: s/something_to_match/replacement.   '/' is very commonly used as the delimiter character, but perl pretty much allows any character that isn't used in the regexes as the delimiter.

See: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html